# Debugging group policies

Tags: group-policy, windows

Begginer with windows servers here
How can i find which group policy is applied when i click on something and get blocked?

I currently can't check for windows updates unless i deactivate the GPOs applied
to that computer. Ofcourse i tried resetting any windows update relevant policies to "Not Configured".
Is there any way to have the event viewer show something along the lines of "action x blocked by policy "Configure Automatic Updates"" for example?

Anything i can find on google is how to log errors in group policies.

Comment: Did you refresh Group Policy on the server after making the change? gpupdate /force

Comment: ofcourse i did :)

Answer (score 6):

`gpresult.exe` and `rsop.msc` are the two main tools for GPO debugging and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the OS you're trying to troubleshoot, but you can run `gpresult /r` for a Windows 7 machine or `gpresult` for a Windows XP machine (from the cmd prompt).  Keep in mind for Windows 7, if you don't run an elevated cmd prompt (Run as Admin), you will only see policies for the logged on user.

You can also use `rsop` from the cmd prompt for Windows 7 machines, which will give you a GUI view of the settings applied and which policies they came from.  Getting RSOP for Windows XP is a bit more involved.  You need to first open a custom MMC console (`mmc.msc` from the run command).  Then you'll need to add the `Resultant Set of Policy` Snap-in.  You can then right click on the RSOP and gather the data.

You could also use the `Group Policy Results` wizard from within the `Group Policy Management Console` if you have rights to do so.

Comment: any os actually. It's not even working on my test DC